# What does the `shiftBind` function here mean?

Tags: function, javascript

In a javascript snippet, I saw codes like this..

```
nglr.shiftBind = function(_this, _function) {
  return function() {
    var args = [ this ];
    for ( var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
      args.push(arguments[i]);
    }
    return _function.apply(_this, args);
  };
};
```

This looks a little abstract for me to understand... Could anyone have an example about what this really does..

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to prepend the current scope (when you call the returned function) to any arguments passed into `_function`, then finally calls it with a specified scope (`_this`).

```js
// Take a new scope and a callback
var shiftBind = function(_this, _function) {
  // Wrap them, creating closure
  return function() {
    // Save the current scope, when you call this function
    var args = [this];
    // Prepend it to any arguments
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
      args.push(arguments[i]);
    }
    // Then call the original function with the original scope argument
    return _function.apply(_this, args);
  };
};


// Test it
function Ctor(foo) {
  this.foo = foo;
}

// Make a pair of Ctors and give x a method
var x = new Ctor(1);
var y = new Ctor(3);

x.getFoo = function(prev) {
  return prev ? prev.foo + this.foo : this.foo;
}

// Check outputs
console.log(x.getFoo()); // 1
console.log(x.getFoo.call(y)); // 3

// Bind so we have access to both "scopes"
x.boundFoo = shiftBind(y, x.getFoo);
console.log(x.boundFoo()); // calls getFoo, which only exists on x, but prints 4
```

This doesn't seem to have a ton of practical uses, and isn't a pattern I've seen before, but allows you to access to objects with `this`-like semantics.

Answer (score 1):

This is creating a new function that changes the `this` of the original function, but adds the original `this` as a first argument. So it's both binding and shifting the arguments down one. I have no idea what its purpose is.

Answer (score 1):

This function you can define what parameter and what kind of parameters(string, number...) you want to pass to a function. example:

```
var nglr = {};

nglr.shiftBind = function(_this, _function) {
  return function() {
    var args = [ this ];
    for ( var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
      args.push(arguments[i]);
    }
    return _function.apply(_this, args);
  };
};

var obj2 = new Object();
obj2.name = '';
// 1. defined a function that is called when the returned function is executed.
var sumFunc = function(obj, param, param2, param3, param4, param5){
  console.log('obj2: ', this); // obj2
  console.log(obj, param, param2, param3, param4, param5); // Window-Object 1 2 3 4 5
  return param + param2 + param3 + param4 + param5;
};

// 2. hold returned function at variable
var returnedFunc = nglr.shiftBind(obj2, sumFunc);

// 3. call returned function, now all parameters that were given to the returned function are passed on to the sumFunc-function plus as first param the object which context the returned function is executed in(in this case Window, because returnedFunc is not called as member-function). 
returnedFunc(1,2,3,4,5); // 15
```

Thats why when you pass a fifth parameter to the returned function but you only defined 4 parameter plus the obj parameter, like this:

```
var sumFunc = function(obj, param, param2, param3, param4){
  console.log(obj, param, param2, param3, param4); // Window-Object 1 2 3 4 
  return param + param2 + param3 + param4;
};
```

It returns 10 not 15:

```
returnedFunc(1,2,3,4,5); // 10
```

Nevertheless you can see the fifth parameter(5) in the arguments-property(at console.log), but it's not defined as sixth parameter in the sumFunc function. And therefore 10 is returned and not 15:

```
var nglr = {};

nglr.shiftBind = function(_this, _function) {
  return function() {
    var args = [ this ];
    console.log(arguments); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    for ( var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
      args.push(arguments[i]);
    }
    return _function.apply(_this, args);
  };
};
```

Furthermore shiftBind means that "this"-property could be a different object when sumFunc is called. In this example obj2 and not nglr:

```
var sumFunc = function(obj, param, param2, param3, param4, param5){
  console.log('obj2: ', this); // obj2 not nglr
  //...
};
```